# getting parent from a variable using batch script

Tags: tomcat, batch-file

I am reading a registry.
Then I get a path inside a variable.
I am doing this as follows:

```
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2*" %%A IN ('%SystemRoot%\system32\REG.exe QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat7\Parameters\Log" /v Path') DO set WorkPath=%%B
```

value of WorkPath is something like "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\logs"

But the problem is I want the parent directory from the variable "WorkPath"
without using "cd" or changing the directory

The path inside "WorkPath" should be "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set "regCmd=%SystemRoot%\system32\REG.exe QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat7\Parameters\Log" /v Path"
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('%regCmd% ^| find "REG_SZ"') DO set "WorkPath=%%~dpB"
```

Changes done:

- Command splitted to better fit on screen, not necessary.
- Replaced `skip` in for clause with `find` to only process the
  intended line (in my system it needs a `skip=4` to only process the
  required line)
- AND, instead of directly assign `%%B` (the value readed from the registry), as it is a path to the log folder, get the path to reach that folder, that is, the path to the parent folder. The value assigned is `%%~dpB`, the drive and path where the folder pointed in `%%B` is located.

Comment: thanks..
the output is "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\"
but that is all i wanted.